# ARM NEON assembler error: "instruction cannot be conditional"

Tags: xcode, math, assembly, arm, neon

According to the [arm info center](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHJCAAG.html) vadd can be executed condtitionally however when i try

```
vaddeq.f32 d0,d0,d1
```

Xcode returns

```
65:instruction cannot be conditional -- vaddeq.f32 d0,d0,d1
```

one thing i've noticed is that it seems to be only NEON instructions that give this error. VFP instructions don't produce these errors.

Is there a compiler flag I have to set in order to enable NEON conditional instructions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ARM Architecture Reference Manual says:

```
 An ARM Advanced SIMD VADD instruction must be unconditional.
```

I.e., if you're in ARM mode, those instructions are not conditional.  You can use them conditionally in Thumb-2 if you put them in an IT block.

```
  .syntax unified
  .code 16
  .globl _foo
_foo:
  cmp r0, #0
  it eq
  vaddeq.f32 d0, d0, d1
  bx lr
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that really clears things up for me, im not going to use Thumb in my code so i guess i'll just stick with branches. Thanks for the great answer though!

Comment: Great.  Now you can go ahead and click the button that accepts this answer, and then do the same for all of the other questions you've asked and that people took the time to answer.

Comment: Sorry im new to stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

The reason why conditional NEON instructions are not available in ARM mode is because they use encodings with the condition field set to NV (never). You need to use conditional branches or (better) rewrite the code to not use the comparison results directly - e.g. set a register to 0 or 1 depending on the result and use its value in further operations.

Answer (score 1):

Only instructions shared by NEON and VFP can be executed conditionally.

(vldmia for example.)

For me, there have been a few situations where conditional execution could have saved me from some minor  headaches, but in general, you won't need it that badly.

Take a careful look at the NEON logical and compare operations. They very well indicate how NEON is supposed to be programmed.

cya.