# ARM Neon: vst cannot be conditional

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I want to store a 64-bit lane only if it's non zero (all 8 bytes are non zero):

```
.text
.arch armv7-a
.fpu neon
.type myfunction, STT_FUNC
.global myfunction

myfunction:
    ...
    vcmp.f64 d12, #0
    vst1ne.u8 {d12}, [outI]!
```

I receive the error message:

```
Error: instruction cannot be conditional -- `vst1ne.u8 {d12},[outI]!'
```

The only work around solution I found is:

```
    vcmp.f64 d12, #0
    vmrs APSR_nzcv, fpscr
    beq .jumpover
    vst1.u8 {d12}, [outI]!
.jumpover:
```

But the switch out of Neon is probably killing the performance. What is wrong with the intial code?

Comment: What the assembler says: That instruction cannot be made conditional. That's what's wrong with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARM NEON assembler error instruction cannot be conditionally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004643/arm-neon-assembler-error-instruction-cannot-be-conditionally)

Comment: Your first comment is of no use at all. As for the second comment, I read that question before posting. I believe my case is different.

Comment: Then could you explain how your question is different? Note than non of the NEON instructions that are not also part of VFP can be executed conditionally. That's what the spec says and that's what is wrong with your original code.

Comment: Even it it could be executed conditionally (which it can't, barring Thumb instructions with a preceding `it`, which is not recommended), conditional execution doesn't use the _FPU_ condition flags; it's literally only the branch instruction itself you're trying to save, which if it's mostly taken (or not taken) in a predictable manner might not be too big a deal anyway. As I said on a previous question, NEON really isn't designed for data-dependent operations, so don't be too surprised when they suck.