# Assembly conditional instruction

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

This is an error message i get when compiling with mfpu=neon:

> Error: instruction cannot be conditional -- `vextne.8 d4,d17,d4,#0'

What's my actual error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARM NEON assembler error: "instruction cannot be conditional"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7004643/253056).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector instructions cannot be conditional since the conditions are stored in the status register but for vector instructions this isn't possible since multiplice (different) values are affected. Vector comparison operations store the result in the vector themselves. You have to approach this problem differently, by using branches for instance or a different set of instructions leading up to this point in your program.